# Execute a bactch file through a PROCEDURE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, batch-processing

I am trying to execute a batch file through a PROCEDURE in MySQL database and in batch file i have some SQL statements like LOAD DATA statements which are not allowed inside the procedure.

SQL Statement:-

```
load data local infile 'D:/test_hospital_master.csv'  
into  table performance
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
```

So I am wondering is there any way to execute a batch file through MySQL procedure?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this from within a stored procedure and not merely from your application code?

Comment: Actually i am not a java developer so I do not have that much experience so I just wanted to use this in my application.